# Accessing Domino server using Android Apps

Tags: android, lotus-domino

I want to read data which is receiding in the domino server database using android application.

Any body has any kind of example/sample program for doing this ? What is the best possible way to read the data from domino using Android.

And also I am interesting in knowing what are the different ways of doing this ?

Comment: There are lots of ways of accessing data in a database on a Lotus Domino server. There are database specific ways (which involves implementing "data access points" if they have not already been implemented using e.g. views functionality, agents written in Lotusscript or Java, XPages, and more) - and there are server specific ways (such as using Domino Access Services to be able to have general REST access to databases, views and documents). It all depends on your specific needs and as such this question is probably to open-ended. Can you get more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question. So I'm going to have to give you a broad answer.

Accessing a data on a Domino server can be done a number of ways. If you design an Android app that can process a REST services then you can either deliver it via XPages services from the Domino server, or use a dedicate Notes "Agent".

If you choose to use an agent, then you'll need to be aware of how to control the output to prevent default html behaviour. You can see what I mean [here](http://www.keysolutions.com/notesfaq/all5x.html#NT000011B2) and a better example [here](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4PSGWL?OpenDocument). If user identity is required, you will need to be able to authenticate. As you want to use an "app", I would recommend a servlet installed on the Domino server and enable it using the [Domino Servlet Engine](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lqkrhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.lotus.quickr.admin.dom.doc/install/qp_inst_servlet_t.html). Be aware of the need to create sessions, you can find a reasonable primer [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/). This should be able to get you started. Personally I found this to be weeks/months of work.

Finally, you can try [Mobilite](http://www.mobilite.com.au) which uses HTML5 and functions on Android as well as Apple devices without the need for coding. (Disclaimer: Please note that [I am a co-founder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193467/giulio) of this product, and I have noted the stackoverflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) regarding self-promotion).

Comment: Using REST Services - By calling dedicated Notes "Agent", I have some idea of controlling the agent output and I can render it in the JSON format. In this approach, How do i authenticate and maintain session state for further querying. I need to authenticate the user and maintain the session state for queying the informaton still the user secession is valid. By calling XPages services ,Can I get any additional information on this ? If i use the servlet then can i be able to authenticate and maintain the secession state ? If i don't enable the Domino Servlet Engine what are the consequences th

Comment: Domino, under the hood, uses an old but effective IBM web server call the "IBM Go Webserver". For servlets, you need to enable SSO in order to get a session token (transferred from the browser as "LtpaToken"), and there is a specific Domino API, "getSessionToken()". You can also use XPages to also do this but I am not sure if you need to enable SSO as well. If you're comfortable with Java, I would use servlets. If you intend to use JSON, check out these libraries from json.org http://www.json.org/java/index.html